# PHP 5.4.4 MySQL Connection

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to migrate an application from PHP 5.2.X to PHP 5.4.4 and I am having a few problems related to how the app connects to the database.

The new server fails on this line:

```
$this->db = @mysql_pconnect(_DBHOST,_DBUSER,_DBPASS);
```

I know that the new versions have changed the way the apps connect to the database but I have been trying to connect with other methods and I couldn't. I think it should be related to the server configuration which can be found here: http://bit.ly/S2px7Q

What I see is that mysqlnd is installed but not the mysql, mysqli or PDO. Is that correct?

Comment: Maybe removing the `@` will shed some light on the cause of the problem, mmm?

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: Also, line is missing a semi-colon and has one too many parentheses - but may just be copy/paste issue.

Comment: You are correct @newfurniturey but that was because I copy pasted :).

Comment: I removed the @ but nothing appears just a IIS page with some internal error. Matt thanks for the article, for now I will try if I can get PDO to work.

Comment: @AgustinLopez What is the internal error? That is what netcoder was trying to get you to look at.

Comment: When using mysql_pconnect(_DBHOST,_DBUSER,_DBPASS) or mysql_connect(_DBHOST,_DBUSER,_DBPASS) I get: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() or Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting `Undefined Function` errors, then it means that the `mysql` library is not installed in your copy of PHP.

This may actually be a good thing, because this particular library is considered obsolete. PHP provides at least two good alternatives which are recommended to use instead.

I recommend that you switch all your `mysql_xxx()` function calls for the equivalent `mysqli_xxx()` calls.

This will allow you to start using a better library with minimal code changes. You could also use the PDO library, but that would involve more work if you're dealing with existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, try PDO

```
$this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mysql", "root", "password");
$this->statement = $db->query('SELECT first_name, last_name FROM users;');
$this->users = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: When I try PDO I get: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver. Do I need to get an extension installed for this? My phpinfo is here http://aaascreening.com/rental/info.php